# Active Qt bug when I use a Web Browser

Tags: c++, qt, activex, qt5.6, activeqt

I'm using Active Qt in the goal to show a Web Browser inside my qt application. I can show a Google Map page inside a Tab. It uses an ActiveX-based component with an Internet Explorer Browser inside. Everything is ok but when I resize the windows with my mouse, I have a strange non-wanted resize to my orignal size (800x600) after 1 or 2 secondes of manual resize.

Do you have a tip to avoid this strange behavior ?

ps : I use Qt 5.6.2 cuz I need about the Windows XP¨compatibilty

Comment: If you just want to display a web page [qt webengine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html) might be easier